# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<500>

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-test-mvc

PTAControllerTest.Java

```
@Test
    public void testCreateProducerTeamAccess() throws Exception {

        String expectedProducerId = "AGT02";

        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
        
        // Instantiate request DTO
        ProducerTeamAccessPk newProducerTeamAccessPk = new ProducerTeamAccessPk(expectedProducerId, "ATL");
        
        ProducerTeamAccessDto requestProducerTeamAccessDto = createMockProducerTeamAccessDto(newProducerTeamAccessPk);

        ProducerTeamAccess createdProducerTeamAccess = producerTeamAccessMapper.map(requestProducerTeamAccessDto);

        Mockito
                .when(producerService.exists(Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(true);
        
        Mockito
                .when(producerTeamAccessRepository.findById(ArgumentMatchers.any(ProducerTeamAccessPk.class)))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(createdProducerTeamAccess));
        
        Mockito
                .when(producerTeamAccessRepository.saveAndFlush(ArgumentMatchers.any(ProducerTeamAccess.class)))
                .thenReturn(createdProducerTeamAccess);

        Mockito
                .doNothing()
                .when(messageSender)
                .sendCreated(Mockito.any(BaseDto.class));

        String requestProducerTeamAccessDtoJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestProducerTeamAccessDto);

        // remove keys that are not allowed to be set
        DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(requestProducerTeamAccessDtoJson);
        doc.delete("links");
        requestProducerTeamAccessDtoJson = doc.jsonString();

        RequestBuilder request = RestDocumentationRequestBuilders
                .post(controllerPath, expectedProducerId)
                .content(requestProducerTeamAccessDtoJson)
                .contentType(CustomMediaType.APPLICATION_AIM_API_V1_JSON_UTF8)
                .accept(CustomMediaType.APPLICATION_AIM_API_V1_JSON_UTF8);

        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc
                .perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andDo(document("{method-name}",
                        resourceDetails()
                                .description("To create a new ProducerTeamAccess resource, POST a JSON resource representation to the /producerTeamAccesss endpoint with the content being a single JSON object containing all of the required ProducerTeamAccess fields, and additionally any optional fields. You may include the TeamId field in your request, but it will be ignored, and instead will be saved with the newly created resource ID as assigned by the server. " +
                                        "Upon acceptance and successful processing a request to create a new ProducerTeamAccess resource, the server will respond with a 201 Created and a Location header indicating the URI of the newly created ProducerTeamAccess resource.")
                                .summary("Create a ProducerTeamAccess resource")
                                .requestSchema(Schema.schema("ProducerTeamAccessDto"))
                                .tag(TAG),
                                pathParameters(
                                        parameterWithName("producerId").description("producerId of the ProducerTeamAccess to create")),
                        getRequestProducerTeamAccessDto(false)))
                .andReturn();
        

    }
```

---

PTAService.java

```
public ProducerTeamAccessDto save(String producerId, ProducerTeamAccessCreateDto producerTeamAccessCreateDto) {

        this.validate(producerId, producerTeamAccessCreateDto);

        ProducerTeamAccess ProducerTeamAccessToSave = producerTeamAccessMapper.mapFromCreateDto(producerTeamAccessCreateDto);

        ProducerTeamAccessToSave.setProducerId(producerId);

        ProducerTeamAccessToSave.setCreatedById(UserSession.getUserId());
        ProducerTeamAccessToSave.setDateAdded(Date.now());
        ProducerTeamAccessToSave.setModifiedById(UserSession.getUserId());
        ProducerTeamAccessToSave.setDateModified(Date.now());

        ProducerTeamAccess newProducerTeamAccess = ProducerTeamAccessRepository.saveAndFlush(ProducerTeamAccessToSave);

        return producerTeamAccessMapper.map(newProducerTeamAccess);
    }
```

---

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> createProducerTeamAccess(
            @PathVariable("producerId") String producerId,
            @RequestBody ProducerTeamAccessCreateDto producerTeamAccessCreateDto, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

        logger.info("Creating ProducerTeamAccess.");
        
        ProducerTeamAccessDto newProducerTeamAccessDto = producerTeamAccessService.save(producerId, producerTeamAccessCreateDto);
        
        try {
            messageSender.sendCreated(newProducerTeamAccessDto);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occured while sending the ProducerTeamAccess create message to the Queue");
        }   
        // redirect to newly created ProducerTeamAccess record
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path(controllerPath + "/{teamId}").buildAndExpand(newProducerTeamAccessDto.getTeamId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);   
    }
```

Comment: I don't think JavaScript is relevant here.

Comment: @RKP First of all correct the code blocks and please provide us detailed description and logs from console

Comment: please also add the stack trace for the test outcome, right now it's quite hard to help.